# Problem in creating an abstract class with cause in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Initially, I want to create an abstract error class with cause field following implementation.

```
abstract class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string, options: { cause: any }) {
    super(message, options);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

class NewError extends CustomError {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message, { cause: "helloworld "});
    }
}

const a = new NewError("helloworld");

console.log("a", a, "a.cause", a.cause)
```

However, I got the error

```
(parameter) options: {
    cause: any;
}
Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.(2554)
```

For now this is my workaround, but I would prefer my first implementation to work, to directly use cause field from Error object.

Can anyone explain to me why first version does not work? What is the possible solution to fix it? Thank you.

```
abstract class CustomError extends Error {
  cause: string | undefined = undefined;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

class NewError extends CustomError {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.cause = "helloworld";
    }
}

const a = new NewError("helloworld");

console.log("a", a, "a.cause", a.cause)
```

If I removed abstract class, it also worked. However, my goal is to able to keep abstract class and make it work.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `super` in `CustomError` with 2 arguments? `Error` only expects 1 argument to its constructor. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The [`cause` property of an `Error` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause) was [introduced to JavaScript with ES2022](https://2ality.com/2022/06/ecmascript-2022.html#error.cause).  If you want to use this in your TypeScript code, you should increase your [`--target` compiler setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to at least `"ES2022"` (or at least change your [`--lib` compiler setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) to include it).  If you do that things will start working.

Keep in mind that if you're trying to support older runtimes then you might want to either polyfill `Error` (such as [this polyfill in `core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-error)) or use your workaround.

[Playground link to code with `--target` of `"ES2022"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgV0gewFsBRKKPKBAUwA8JKA7AEwxLIoG8BYAKAST3qQo2eOQAUBSumABzSgC4EQgJb0ZAGgR4ADhGUCwi9kmC4FCYPQCeCAL4BKBF158l2bZSgSpYWZU06egb2ANwIAPThWgDWwFY8rggA8iAAVpTwAHRglBAACmQQeBBWHkkAZmIQABbKYJr0lADumRDAUHIQmdqFxaWUoQl2PLY8PChoGAByzazkVLQMzFi4RcSk886JsAbQIkVektJyiipqjluJrmDunt7H-k4mZooARNWUyMh4TeTIjAhXg4QkM+KNuODxrsLAgALwIRpNBAzJpzLzvT7fX5Qf6vQbcKGCPDISiZb4yMSvYCvTTATRUzKwUw5GkWRnMgZjbiIhBosT2IA).